# Why does findViewById() returns "null"?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I have an important issue with java
I have this code :

```java
package fr.christian.lbcde;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import fr.christian.lbcde.ui.main.PageViewModel;
import fr.christian.lbcde.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PageViewModel pageViewModel;
    View activity_main, tab_create, tab_connect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pageViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        tab_connect = findViewById(R.id.tab_connect);
        tab_create = findViewById(R.id.tab_create);
        System.out.print("Result of tab_connect : ");
        System.out.print(findViewById(R.id.tab_connect));
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(tab_connect==null);
        System.out.print("Result of tab_create : ");
        System.out.print(findViewById(R.id.tab_create));
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(tab_create==null);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addNew();
            }
        });
//        hideAll();
//        tab_connect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pageViewModel.addTabListener(new PageViewModel.tabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChangeTab(View view, int tab) {
                switch (tab) {
                    case 1:
                        hideAll();
                        tab_connect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        hideAll();
                        tab_create.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    default:
                        new Toast(getApplicationContext())
                                .makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rien a afficher pour cet onglet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addNew() {
        new Toast(getApplicationContext())
                .makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cette option n'est pas encore disponible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    public void hideAll() {
        View[] views = {
                tab_create,
                tab_connect
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
            views[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        ;
    }

}
```

and four files for my layouts : 

activity main.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LeBonCoinDeLÉvangile.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryVariant"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.PlaceholderFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <include layout="@layout/login_main"/>
            <include layout="@layout/create_main"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

create_main.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab_create"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TAB_CREATE"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BONJOUR LES ÉLËPHANTS"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and login_main.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab_connect"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TAB_CONNECT"/>
    <TextView
        style="@style/h2textStyle"
        android:text="@string/titleConnect_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginConnect_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that at the lines :

```java
System.out.print(findViewById(R.id.tab_connect));
```

and

```java
System.out.print(findViewById(R.id.tab_create));
```

I have this result (for the both) :

```
null
```

So I can't remove the error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference" in `hideAll()`, `tab_create.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`, etc... because when I initialize my layouts, they are initialized with **a null object** (and not my layouts).
I add some lines like

```xml
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TAB_CREATE"/>
```

in my file to see if those tabs are really those I see on my screen and its appear that I really see them (when I cancel the lines with the layouts visibility). 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: See : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView

Comment: Ok, the problem isn't here (but thanks you still), I use a tabbed activity, so each tab contain on _fragment_main_ different each others, so I have to edit contents in the PlaceholderFragment.java file. I couldn't answer to myself because I don't have enough reputation 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tab_connect` etc. are `include`d in `fragment_main` layout and not in `activity_main` layout that is inflated when you call `findViewById()` for those ids. The code you posted does not show where you're using `fragment_main` but what is certain is that it is not in your activity's view hierarchy at the time when you try to look up those views.

Either move the `findViewById()` calls and whatever you're doing with the views to the fragment, or move the views from the fragment to your main activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will verify but if I can see the content of the linear layouts normally they are in the XML hierarchy

Comment: They are part of the view hierarchy eventually but not at the time of activity onCreate()

Comment: Sorry it is not really my job so I don't understand really what it changes sorry.

Comment: I pushed fragment main but I didn't closed activity main code correctly so fragment main is just under sorry. I arrange that now

Comment: Ok, I realized that the linear layout that I see in one tab is cloned on a second tab, so I have two linear layouts indentic because there are in two different tabs, but when I change per example the EditText text in one tab, it doesn't change those in the second tab. So I don't have really a tab_create layout